# How to log/dump/outout dom html

Tags: karma-runner

I've tried:

```
console.log(element('.users').html());
```

but the only thing I get is

```
LOG: { name: 'element \'.users\' html', fulfilled: false }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using Angular scenario runner.

The `element().html()` dsl returns a future (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises)). You are logging the future that will eventually contain the element, but at the point when you are calling `console.log`, the future is not resolved yet - there is no value in there.

Try this:

```
element('.users').query(function(elm, done) {
  console.log(elm.html());
  done();
});
```

The whole scenario runner works as a queue. The test code is executed (synchronously) and each command (eg. `element().html` in your case) adds some action into this queue. Then, these actions are executed asynchronously - once first action finishes (by calling `done()`), the second action is executed, etc... Therefore the individual actions can be asynchronous, but the test code is synchronous, which is more readable.